# TortoiseGIT Source Code - how to use git to save wincred?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I can't find the entrance in tortoisegit source.please tell me what the object is to save username or password.

Comment: See if `Right Click->TortoiseGit->Settings->Git->Credential` is what you want.

Comment: think you very match! I just want to knows the tortoisegit source of the method,don't the UI set.